# Cross-browser 'cursor:pointer'

Tags: css

I [found these CSS attributes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csscursors.shtml), that make the cursor look like a hand:

- **IE** - style="cursor: hand;"
- **NS6/ IE6** - style="cursor: pointer;"
- **Cross Browser** - style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;"

However I notice that Stack Overflow is using "cursor: pointer" in its CSS.
However, this apparently work also on IE.

So ... what gives? What is the correct, browser-independent way to use this CSS item?

Comment: Just an aside, if you are looking up web development tutorials and the page you land on mentions anything about DHTML, then you should immediately recognise that it is about 10 years out of date. While we technically still use DHTML today, the term is not very widely used.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

According to [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html), the only cross-browser syntax is:

```
element {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

They give some more information about the cursor as well:

> In the past the hand value was
>   Microsoft's way of saying pointer; and
>   IE 5.0 and 5.5 only support hand.
>   Because it's the cursor value that's
>   used most often, most other browsers
>   have also implemented hand.
>
> Since IE 6 and 7 support pointer,
>   there's no more reason to use hand,
>   except when older IEs are part of your
>   target audience.

I think the page you linked to might be a little outdated with the newest browsers.

Answer (score 11):

I've only ever used `cursor:pointer` myself, and have noticed no lack of support in major browsers.