# My Image is not getting on hover effect in IE 7.0

Tags: css

I have a markup in this way

```
<a href="http://abc.com/">
<span class="symbol"> </span>    
</a>
```

CSS

```
background-image: url("socialsymbol.png");
background-position: ;
height:  ;
width: ;
cursor:pointer
```

My Problem is when i hover on the image/span it is changing to hand symbol in all the browsers except IE.7.0 what might be the problem ?

Comment: You've tagged this as `css-selectors` but you haven't actually shown us which selector you're using.

Comment: You also didn't close you `cursor:pointer`, don't forget the`;` unless you just didn't copy it for here.

Comment: @JoshPowell: You could leave the ';' away, if it was the last line inside of the selector, right?

Comment: @StefanSurkamp I believe you are correct, after looking through w3's information on selectors it seems some can end without while others do. It would help to see the entire selector that they are using. :]

Comment: Personally, I find find it more consistent if you're always using semicolons at the end of a line; especially if you add additional lines later on, there's the danger of forgetting to add the omitted ';'

Comment: Also why do you have all these empty declarations?

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer at [Cross-browser 'cursor:pointer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076468/cross-browser-cursorpointer-at-stackoverflow).

It proposes

```
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
```

as a cross-browser solution.

Comment: `cursor: pointer;` works fine in IE7. Heck, it even works in IE6!

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to define height and width try this

```
<style>
.symbol{
background-image: url("socialsymbol.png");
background-position: ;
height: 100px  ;
width: 100px;
cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```