# html contenteditable attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the mouse cursor to be set to pointer when `<body contenteditable="true">`. This needs to work in internet explorer for legacy reasons.

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Cursor Test</title>
</head>

<body contenteditable="true">
  <p>This is Editable editable
    <p>
      <a style="cursor: pointer;" href="https://www.google.com/">I want this 
     link clickable with pointer cursor here</a>
</body>

</html>
```

This works nicely in Chrome but not in internet explorer. When hovering over a link I see a mouse pointer in Chrome but not in I.E.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-browser 'cursor:pointer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076468/cross-browser-cursorpointer)

Comment: If any of the answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cursor: pointer` and `cursor: hand` to cover all browsers and `[contenteditable="true"]` to identify the elements with the contenteditable attribute.

```
*[contenteditable="true"] {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
*[contenteditable="true"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}


/* not relevant - styling only */
div {
  height: 75px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">pointer</div>
<div contenteditable="false">default</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

mark `contenteditale` as `false` in the `<a>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is Editable editable<p>
    <a contenteditable="false" style="cursor: pointer;" href="https://www.google.com/">
        I want this link clickable with pointer cursor here
    </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The picture you've attached shows that the basic `contenteditable` *is* supported, just not the optional values. See the top row of the table.

Comment: This may provide a reference but does not actually answer the question of HOW.

Comment: sure i guess you guys are right. hang on i'll just post an update

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make your css internal and edit it as follows :

```
a:hover { cursor:pointer; }
```

It should work.

Comment: The `:hover`-selector is not necessary on when applying `cursor`. Your CSS is no different to his own CSS.